Service for real-time notifications and tracking app metrics?
I’m looking for a service (with an API and mobile app) that allows me to receive real-time notifications on my phone for specific events in my web app (e.g., user sign-ups). I’d also like it to include a simple dashboard for tracking metrics, like the total number of sign-ups.
I’ve checked out Pushover, but it doesn’t have metrics or a dashboard. Also GA doesn't have push notification on mobile app.
Any recommendations?
